# mongodb find() returns entire db, even with parameter

Tags: json, mongodb

I have the following db:

```
{
    "a": [{
        "name": "foo",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "bar",
            "lyrics": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "abc",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "123",
            "list": ["one", "two"]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I can't seem to query it correctly. These two queries return the same thing, the entire db:

> db.test.find({"a.name":"abc"})
>
> db.test.find({"a.name":"foo"})

How do I find one collection instead of the whole db?

I would expect the first query to return:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "thing": [{
      "name": "123",
      "list": ["one", "two"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: So your database contains one item, with one key `a`?

Comment: I'm new to JSON. Is there a better way to format this? I can get rid of "a". I have a long list of items like "foo" and "abc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries return the same document, because both queries match it.

This is one document

```
[{
    "a": [{
        "name": "foo",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "bar",
            "lyrics": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "abc",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "123",
            "list": ["one", "two"]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

This is two documents

```
[{
    "a": [{
        "name": "foo",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "bar",
            "lyrics": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "a": [{
        "name": "abc",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "123",
            "list": ["one", "two"]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

You can get stats on of a collection like so
`db.test.stats()`
`"count"` will tell you how many documents are there.

Edit: To add to this, in your collection "test" a document has 1 field, which is "a" and is of type array that holds objects (documents). It has 2 array elements

First

```
{
        "name": "foo",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "bar",
            "lyrics": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
}
```

Second

```
{
        "name": "abc",
        "thing": [{
            "name": "123",
            "list": ["one", "two"]
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside curly braces `{..}`, including the braces themselves, is a one single document, i.e. the whole your database contains only one document that you receive for any matching query. To receive the desired result, you have to re-write your JSON document as an array of documents inside square braces `[..]`.